# Removing a single item from Kivy mdlist

Tags: python, mobile, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to be able to remove an item from an mdlist when the trash button is pressed.I have tried getting each specific item through its text but whenever i delete everything,one item is always left.I have even tried to create a list that deletes items present on th list but i was not able to get it to work.It kept deleting the very last item on the list.
I have run out of ideas an would really appreciate any help i can get.Below is a reproducable version of the code

```
def delete_item2(self, instance):
        container = self.manager.get_screen("checkout").ids.container2
        if len(self.widget_list)>1:
            for child in list(container.children):
                if "1L" in child.text:
                    container.remove_widget(child)
                    break
                elif "5L"in child.text:
                    container.remove_widget(child)
                    break
```

.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

Window.size = (350, 600)
mykv = """
<CheckoutScreen>:
    name: "checkout"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDTopAppBar:
            title: "Checkout"
            left_action_items: [["arrow-left", lambda x: root.browse_screen(), "BACK"]]
            
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: container2
                TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                    text: "ITEM 1"
                    secondary_text: "Secondary text here"

                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: "trash-can"
                        on_press:root.delete_item2()

                   
                TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                    text: "ITEM 2"
                    secondary_text: "Secondary text here"

                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: "trash-can"
                        on_press:root.delete_item2()

"""

class CheckoutScreen(MDScreen):
    
    def delete_item2(self):
        #container = self.manager.get_screen("checkout").ids.container2
        print("delete item called")
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(mykv)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(CheckoutScreen(name="checkout"))
        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the item to be deleted to the `delete_item2()` method. First, assign `ids` to each item, then use that item in the call to `delete_item2()`:

```
        MDList:
            id: container2
            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: item1
                text: "ITEM 1"
                secondary_text: "Secondary text here"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "trash-can"
                    on_press:root.delete_item2(item1)


            TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:
                id: item2
                text: "ITEM 2"
                secondary_text: "Secondary text here"

                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "trash-can"
                    on_press:root.delete_item2(item2)
```

Then the `delete_item2()` method becomes simple:

```
def delete_item2(self, item):
    print("delete item called", item)
    self.ids.container2.remove_widget(item)
```

However, if you are adding the `TwoLineAvatarIconListItem` to the `MDList` dynamically (and therefore cannot create `ids`), you can also call the `delete_item2()` as:

```
on_press:root.delete_item2(self.parent.parent)
```